# Listing all possible OSErrors in Python's Stdlib

Tags: python, oserror

I would like to list all the functions and methods in the Python standard library that could throw an `OSError`. Do you know of a way to find that out per python version?

I thought about running an AST on the C code, but I wonder if there is a simpler way (maybe dynamically).

Comment: That will be interesting to implement ~~

Answer (score 1):

I will tell you hard/Ugly `process`

1. Import 'library` that you want to analyze
2. use `inspect` library to get source code of the particular `library` like

   ```
    import re

    import inspect

    lines = inspect.getsource(re)

    print(lines)
   ```

runing
`type(lines)` ---> `output: str`

so we can apply some thing like `regurlar expressions`? to hunt that `keyword` aka `os error`...

To list all the fun inside program

```
import re
re.findall('def (.+?)\s?\(', lines)
```

output

```
['__repr__',
 'match',
 'fullmatch',
 'search',
 'sub',
 'subn',
 'split',
 'findall',
 'finditer',
 'compile',
 'purge',
 'template',
 'escape',
 '_compile',
 '_compile_repl',
 '_expand',
 '_subx',
 'filter',
 '_pickle',
 '__init__',
 'scan']
```

to get all the errors inside the programs

```
re.findall('raise (.+?)\s?\(', lines)
```

output

```
['ValueError', 'TypeError']
```

still program is not finished...Next steps you need to implement is

using `Regx` you need to find text between 2 keywords in our case `def` &  `os error` (you have to do it)....It will spit out some text...

```
def name():
    some code
    some code
    raise error()
    return
```

After the extracting text between keywords output will be something like

```
#output str after applying `re`
     name():
          some code
          some code
          raise error(
```

From the output just print the `text` before `(` using `regex` as program pattern gives `function` name with `particular error` you looking for

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate the contents of the target module, use `inspect` to filter for classes, and then test if `OSError` is part of the base class list:

```py
import inspect

module = globals()['__builtins__']

for name, value in module.__dict__.items():
    if inspect.isclass(value) and OSError in value.__bases__:
        print(name)
```